# How to enable Persian support in GNOME terminal?

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, mariadb

I have Persian character in my MariaDB database, when I select data from tables and show in terminal, Persian is not supported and bad are displayed.

[image: img]

Comment: 1) Which charset do you use in mariadb? https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/setting-character-sets-and-collations/ 2) Which charset do you use (by default) in terminal? Use command `echo $LANG` to show it

Comment: My problem is not the mariadb, but my problem is terminal. When I type in the terminal, this problem occurs. @AnFi.

Comment: Your problem is cases by differences in configuration.  It would help to know charset produced/offered by mariadb and charset expected by gnome-terminal.

Comment: The output of `echo $LANG` command is `en_US.UTF-8`. @AnFi

Comment: Select Persian (MAC_FARSI) charset in gnome-terminal [menu: "Terminal" sub-menu "Set Character encoding"].  Does it fix the problem?

Comment: MAC_FARSI is disabled for me and can not select it. @AnFi